# Django-socialauth and Django-social-auth are two different python packages

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[django-socialauth](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-socialauth/) and [django-social-auth](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-social-auth/) are two different Django apps, and yet Stackoverflow only allows for the `django-socialauth` tag since it thinks that `django-social-auth` is a duplicate tag.

Comment: Whoever created the second of these apps has questions to answer :)